# Сортировка карты против алфивита

Tags: карты, сортировка, java

```
Map<String,String> map = new TreeMap<String,String>();
    map.put("Belorusia", "Minsk");
    map.put("Ukraine", "Kiev");
    map.put("Russia", "Moskva");
    map.put("Iralia", "Rim");
```

`treemap` хранить все значения по алфавиту, без сохранения порядка в котором положили элементы, а как отсортировать значения карты против алфавита? Не помню точно, но использовался такой способ:

`Map<String,String> map = new TreeMap<String,String>`(//Вот здесь что-то писали, может быть что то связанное с `iterable`)
При выводе карта была отсортирована против алфавита? Какой код может использоваться в скобках?

Comment: Вам нужен Comarator. См. документацию к классу TreeMap (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<String, String> map = new TreeMap<String, String>(Collections.reverseOrder());
map.put("Belorusia", "Minsk");
map.put("Ukraine", "Kiev");
map.put("Russia", "Moskva");
map.put("Iralia", "Rim");

for(String country : map.keySet())
{
    System.out.println(country);
}
```

Вывод:

```
Ukraine
Russia
Iralia
Belorusia
```